# Magento 1 PHPDoc syntax incorrect?

Tags: magento-1, ee-1.14.2.0, documentation

I've noticed the following style PHPDoc declarations in Magento core code, and subsequently copied in Magento extensions:

```
/** @var $varName Mage_Core_Model_Example */
```

Should it not follow the [`@var [type] [$optionalName] [Optional comment]` concept](http://www.phpdoc.org/docs/latest/references/phpdoc/tags/var.html) that PHPDoc uses? Eg:

```
/** @var Mage_Core_Model_Example $optionalVarNameOrComment Optional comment here */
```

Or more simply in practice:

```
/** @var Mage_Core_Model_Example */
$example = Mage::getModel('core/example');
```

---

*Edit:* maybe it's just inconsistency among their development team... I found an example of what I would consider a correct `@var` block while reviewing the EE 1.14.2 changes:

```
# app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/Sales/Order/Create.php - 1531:
/** @var Mage_Sales_Model_Order $oldOrder */
```

Comment: I know from my own experience, that NetBeans IDE used to only work with `/** @var $varName Mage_Core_Model_Example */` and also only _after_ the line where the var was defined (as you will also see at many places in Magento code)

Comment: At least for PHPStorm (no clue about the real php doc definition) both works.

Comment: Both appear to work as well in Zend Studio, though I'm testing on CE and not EE...

Comment: So I guess it's a stylistic thing only then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will not get a satisfactory answer unless there are Magento 1 coding regulations published somewhere.

However, Magento 1 follows the [Zend Coding Standard](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/coding-standard.html), which in turn [references to PHPDoc](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/coding-standard.coding-style.html#coding-standards.inline-documentation.documentation-format). So in theory, your observation is correct.

In practice, any regulations towards PHPDoc may not have been too strict, not forced by automatic validation. In consequence, developers did what worked depending on their IDE. PHPStorm supports both variations. Netbeans and Eclipse one and the other – t.b.c.

For Magento 2 there are [published standards which explicitly allow both formats](https://wiki.magento.com/display/MAGE2DOC/Magento+Coding+Standard+for+Documentation+Blocks#MagentoCodingStandardforDocumentationBlocks-@var).